# fstream not creating text file

Tags: c++, string, fstream

It seems when I try to run this source of code, instead of making an Attempt1.txt, or Attempt2.txt, or Attempt3.txt, it simply just makes a FILE named Attempt.

```
    string str;
    int num_attempts_x_million = 1;

    str = "Attempt";
    str += num_attempts_x_million;
    str += ".txt";
    textfile.open(str); 
    textfile << password << endl;
    textfile.close();
```

Comment: You didn't tell us what `str` is, what type `num_attempts_x_million` is or what `textfile` is. So how can we understand this code?

Comment: You can't convert integer to string that way. Try stringstream.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You might be appending control characters, not 'regular' characters. This is assuming, of course, that the type of `num_attempts_x_million` is an `int` (or any integer type).

`std::string::operator+=` does not have an overload for `int`. Instead, it has one for `char` so it casts it into a `char` first and then appends it. For low integer values, this ends up with things like `0x0`, `0x1`, `0x2`, etc which are known as [control characters in ASCII](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ascii).

In order for you to convert the integer into a string you have to use [`std::to_string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string).

Comment: This should have been the accepted answer, because it teaches the OP what the problem was, and why

Answer (score 2):

```
str = "Attempt";
str += std::to_string(num_attempts_x_million);
str += ".txt";
textfile.open(str); 
textfile << password << endl;
textfile.close();
```